# Using delete property without affecting parent object

Tags: javascript

Here are two **objects** named `primary` and `secondary`:

```
var primary = {"gonna":3,"lol":114,"wouldn":2,"know":6,"lowkey":2,"man":5};
var secondary = primary;
```

When I use `delete secondary['lol'];` it deletes the property from both objects: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neptune001/ubLjj1jx/)

My question is: how to delete a property from `secondary` without deleting it from `primary`?

Comment: You assign _reference_ of primary to variable secondary. It's still one object in memory. You need to clone primary to achieve desired behavior.

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate. I'm sure this question has already been asked.

Comment: The OP would have to know that the issue was caused by not copying the object first, before knowing to look at ways to clone an object. Also, it's an object here, not an array.

Comment: @LGSon You apparently don't know the difference between an object and an array, which can only confuse matters

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I do, retracted my vote, .. was a little too sleepy :), so thanks for wake me up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`secondary` is referencing the same object as `primary`. You need to create a copy of `primary` if you want to keep them separate.

There are libraries like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) that have utility functions allowing you to clone an object (below example), but [there are other ways too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).

```js
var primary = {"gonna":3,"lol":114,"wouldn":2,"know":6,"lowkey":2,"man":5};
var secondary = _.clone(primary);

delete secondary.lol;

document.write(JSON.stringify(primary));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(secondary));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create fiddle mean create working fiddle, not just paste a code

http://jsfiddle.net/Lso7kwLs/

Cloning the object help you. For example:

```
var secondary = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(primary));
```

Comment: This actually worked, after object.assign and object destructuring failed to serve the purpose

Answer (score 1):

You should try :

`var primary = {"gonna":3,"lol":114,"wouldn":2,"know":6,"lowkey":2,"man":5};
var secondary = $.extend({}, primary);
delete secondary['lol'];`